# Add a custom notification led light

Tags: java, android

I have a phone under Android 8 and I begin Android programmation with Android Studio. Some apps like Snapchat or Facebook makes my phone light a led with their custom colors (yellow & blue) when a notification comes.

I want to do the same with my app, I searched a lot and nothing works, the notification appears but not the white light. I checked my phone settings and my app is allowed to light the led.

```
public class Notification
{
    public Notification(String channelId, String channelName, Context context, String title, String body, Intent intent)
    {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            int notificationId = 1;
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            {
                 NotificationChannel mChannel = new 
                 NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
                 notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }

            NotificationCompat.Builder nbuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                     .setLights(Color.WHITE, 500, 100) // doesn't work
                     .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 }) // doesn't work
                     .setContentTitle(title)
                     .setContentText(body);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = 
            TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = 
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            nbuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, nbuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I tried calling the `setLights()` and `setVibrate()` after `setContentText()` and I tried calling these voids just before the notify() but it didn't changed anything.

I instanciate my class in the `onCreate()` :

```
new Notification("channel-01", "MathWellan Notification", this, "Twitter", "Follow me on Twitter !", new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name=MathWellan")));
```

Sorry for my bad english, I'm french and I hope you can help me !
Thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this line of code to change notification LED color: `your_notification.ledARGB = Color.YOUR_COLOR;`

**Usage example:**

```
NotificationManager notif = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notif.cancel(1); // clear previous notification 
    final Notification notification = new Notification();

    notification.ledARGB = Color.MAGENTA;

    notification.ledOnMS = 1000;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notif.notify(1, notification);
```

**Note** : screen should be locked when you test it , because notification LED will be highlighted only when screen is off. **Maybe** that's your problem.

Comment: But I notify a NotificationCompat.Builder and in your android.app.Notification I can't edit a text and a title ?

Comment: Try using what I gave you, it seems like it doesn't work with this builder.

Comment: "Application has stopped"

Comment: Look at my edit and apply it to your code. also, why did it stopped? logs plz

Comment: I run directly with my device plugged, I don't have logs after the build success. Also I did a test with the screen off, it seems to not work better !

Comment: Please share your crush logs with me.if your'e using android studio you can see them at the 'Run' tab down there. MARKED RED

Comment: @MathWellan First of all, nice 1 on that OnePlus 5. Secondly, try using this code, it works. [code link](https://pastebin.com/ASjngV4p)

Comment: I created a new project to put your code, and the app still stops